# welling yxb-250-4 induction motor spin start direction is inconsistent

Tags: induction-motor, single-phase

This motor is also often referenced as W11283592. The best pictures of it are in http://www.gmcc-welling.com/Homeen/Product/detail/id/187.html and https://partsdr.com/part/w11283592-drive-motor.
The most informative site I found is 
https://partsdr.com/part/w11283592-drive-motor
 There I found a sentence: "The motor should measure between 3.5 to 6 ohms through both the clockwise and counterclockwise windings."

My connector has 4 wires:

1. Earth ground - green.
2. Black
3. Yellow
4. Red

Black to Yellow -> resistance is 5 Ohm
Black to Red -> resistance is 5 Ohm
Yellow to Red -> resistance is 10.1 Ohm

No connection from Green to other wires.

When I connect 120V AC to Black and Yellow the motor can spin in CW or CCW direction.
When I connect 120V AC to Black and Red the motor can spin also in CW or CCW direction.

From the statement on the Sears site I expected direction of the spin to be stable and consistent based on the wire that is energized.

Am I wrong or is there something wrong with the motor? 3rd option?
Confused...
And frustrated, since I can not find a Service manual for any of the washing machines that use it. Chinese motor in an american product... Tech support is minimal.

**Update 1**: I've ordered and received a 50 uF running cap. Here is the spec: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1796777.pdf
I've connected it in series with the red wire, and now the motor starts CW every time. So far I've not tried to disconnect the cap once the motor is running. So far so good, but no load yet either.

It looks like Sears web page mislead me (or I misunderstood) - I thought it implied that the 2nd winding was only for the CCW operation.

Answer (score 3):

The motor requires a capacitor for starting. One of the red or yellow wires is connected directly to 120V, the other is connected in series with a capacitor to 120V. Judging from the capacitor value, I expect that the capacitor is for starting only. It must be disconnected when the motor gets to full speed. Note where Cap: 50uF is marked on the label. If you have been doing that and have failed to mention it, the capacitor is probably bad or the connecting and disconnecting mechanism is bad.

A 50uF PSC cap seems to be typical for a 2 or 3 Hp motor. It is possible that this 1/3 Hp motor is a PSC (permanently-connected, split-phase capacitor) motor with a 50uF cap, but it seems quite unlikely. Since the motor is specified for use only in a clothes washer it seems likely that the connect/disconnect method is a timer or current sensor in the washer.

However, it also seems likely that the motor will start consistently without a load in the selected direction with about any value of PSC run-type capacitor that may be tried. It is probably ok to try about any value, but don't run the motor with a continuous total current higher than the 3.5 amps marked on the nameplate. The motor may start under load or may not depending on the capacitor value and the load's starting torque requirement.

[image]

Comment: I saw that note about 50uF Cap, but it is no where in site. Since it is listed on the label I assumed that the Cap is buried inside the motor frame, as is connect/disconnect mechanism if it exists inside the frame. But even when I took out the rotor - I did not see the cap.

Comment: Both the capacitor and the disconnect mechanism are probably inside the washer.

Comment: At only 50 uF, the cap may be a permanently connected run capacitor. If you can't hear the click of a centrifugal switch operating as the motor spins down when powered off. it's quite likely. If the motor shows DC resistance on both windings I would expect the cap to be external.

Comment: @Brian Drummond; thank you, see revised answer.

Comment: Good point about the disconnect likely being in the controller. Sounds like examining the controller would be the next logical step.

Answer (score 1):

The cap is external, since this motor is primarily used for laundry washers the cap is mounted to tbe gearcase assy next to the motor.